# json deserialize error

Tags: json

I'm getting frustrated with an "Unknown field" error when I invoke deserializeStrict.  Simple application, all strings...

My apex class contains this public class:

```
 public class CustomerInfo{ 
        public String CustomerNo {get; set;}
        public String CustomerName {get; set;}
        public String Address1 {get; set;}
        public String Address2 {get; set;}
        public String City {get; set;}
        public String State {get; set;}
        public String Zip {get; set;}
        public String County {get; set;}
        public String Country {get; set;}
        public String CreditBlock {get; set;}
        public String CreditLimit {get; set;}
    }
```

Field names are all correct, I have hard-coded the strings that are returned from the webservice...
HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
CustomerInfo newCust = (CustomerInfo)System.JSON.deserializeStrict(res.getBody(), CustomerInfo.class);

The data comes back correctly formatted:

```
{"Address1":"address1 east 1st street","Address2":"suite 305","City":"Walnut","Country":"United States","County":"Douglas","CreditBlock":"No","CreditLimit":"500000","CustomerName":"My Test Customer","CustomerNo":"123456","State":"IA","Zip":"51323"}
```

Error in devloper console log:

```
"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Unknown field: JSONTest.CustomerInfo.GetCustomerInfoResult"|0x569159be
```

ANY help is greatly appreciated!  I don't know what else to do, if I use deserialze rather than deserializeStrict all values in the new object are null...

Comment: sounds like the response has more data in it that you're showing. add a System.debug(res.getBody()) and see what that says

Comment: The data I have displayed is from the System.debug: 12:01:51:130 USER_DEBUG [77]|DEBUG|Fulfillment service returned {"GetCustomerInfoResult":{"Address1":"address1 east 1st street","Address2":"suite 305","City":"Walnut","Country":"United States","County":"Douglas","CreditBlock":"True","CreditLimit":"500000","CustomerName":"My Test Customer","CustomerNo":"123456","State":"IA","Zip":"51323"}}

Comment: You're trying to deserialize the GetCustomerInfoResult rather than the CustomerInfo bit, it will work fine if you get the child JSON contained in the GetCustomerInfoResult

Comment: Thanks for the response, my first experience with json obviously...I have a method:                  public static void getCustomerInfo(string custid) that makes a call to a WCF web service that returns "GetCustomerInfoResult":....so how do I navigate to the child string?

Comment: Also, http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ is a great resource for quickly converting JSON to a simple Apex class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your customerInfo data is nested inside another object in the JSON, you'll need to match that in your apex class structure, so you'll need to add an additional class,

```
public class CustomerInfoResult {
    public CustomerInfo GetCustomerInfoResult;
}
```

then you can deserialize it and access the nested result e.g.

```
CustomerInfo i = ((CustomerInfoResult)JSON.deserializeString(res.getBody(), CustomerInfoResult.class)).GetCustomerInfoResult;
```